# How to limit array depth in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to get up to 10 level in multidimensional array.

Here is my code from which i get up-to infinite depth, but i want to limit this to 10 levels.

```
function tree($parent){
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE parent_id = $parent ";


$users=$db->query($sql);

$return = array();

while($parent = $users->fetchObject()) {

  $return[$parent->client_id] = $parent;


  if(have_data($parent->client_id)){

    $return[$parent->client_id]->subs = tree($parent->client_id);
  }
}

return $return;
}
```

print_r(tree(1,0));

the output is:

```
  Array
    (
    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [client_id] => 2
        [parent_id] => 1
        [client_name] => TEST
        [subs] => Array
            (
                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [client_id] => 4
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [client_name] => TEST
                        [subs] => Array
                            (
                                [5] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [client_id] => 5
                                        [parent_id] => 4
                                        [client_name] => ADAm
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [client_id] => 6
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [client_name] => RAS
                        [subs] => Array
                            (
                                [7] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [client_id] => 7
                                        [parent_id] => 6
                                        [client_name] => RAStest
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [client_id] => 3
        [parent_id] => 1
        [client_name] => ABC
    )

  )
```

How can i limit the child level to 10, Hope to get response from the experts boss.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already seem to have the right idea; you are calling your function with 2 parameters although currently it only accepts 1. Add a second and use it for the depth.

Comment: Hi, i was trying to pass another parameter for passing level value And  in loop i used $level++ but it doesn't worked , it only work for first child depth

Comment: Did you send the modified value of `$level` as the second parameter? If you increment in the function call itself, you need `tree($parent->client_id, ++$level);` to make sure the variable gets incremented *before* it is sent.

Comment: When i sent the increment value it works but for the second loop of the parents first level the value wont be same, so when i checked for level 10 it doesn't provide right value from the second, third parent of first  level

Comment: i think the problem has solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RecursiveIteratorIterator API](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and use [setMaxDepth()](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.setmaxdepth.php) function and can get the maxDepth with this function [getMaxDepth()](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getmaxdepth.php)

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($myArray));
```

Comment: Can you help me by implementing this in my code?? i cant understand. Thank you